# Open PDF file with my APP

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf, ios10, pdf-viewer

I am trying to add an option so that while pressing the share button of a PDF file it'll suggest opening with my app. Like this:

[image]

Currently my plist file has `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` properties and lookes like this:

[image]

[image]

I've followed [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/83djxa/registering-your-app-to-be-able-to-open-images-from-other-apps) but no luck. My app doesn't show up in the list. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have the `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` for PDF. PDF is a standard provided UTI so you should not be declaring your own non-standard UTI. You only ned the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` section with the correct UTI for PDF files, not your made up one.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alertnate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: how do I register my app to handle navigation requests

Comment: @al_mukthar you can implement `application(_:open:options:)` on your `AppDelegate`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application

Answer (score 0):

After adding com.adobe.pdf in  CFBundleDocumentTypes- info.plist files , ios allow to open pdf file with your app. Sharing with yourApp is different thing.

To check how it works with what you have done, Open pdf in safari and check open with menu, you will see your app there.

To get Share With Option (the way you have described in screenshot) , you need to implement share extension. You can read more about it from   [Apple's Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1)

Update:

for supporting PDF documents, LScontentItemTypes should contain "com.adobe.pdf"

Comment: @iOS_developer> I tried that before. But safari does not show my app icon.

Comment: @Drongo I think problem in plist settings, value in   LSItemContentTypes  should contain "com.adobe.pdf" and Item name can be anything like "PDF Document"

Comment: public.pdf is not valid content type.